# Using PHP to load Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables

**EDIT: My function was broken, with the `/n` in it. Thanks woofmeow for leading me to question my function!**

I am new to programming. I have been trying my best and I have learned a lot the past few months (a bunch here!) but I am stumped.

I have a PHP script that calls from another PHP script and I cannot get the code to actually run. It used to run, then I changed some things and didn't save the changes, I'm not sure what I did. I know, I know, rookie mistake(I learned from it!). The Javascript shows up fine on view page source but doesn't run anymore.

Here is the page source, maybe it is that simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delete_user(user_id) 
{if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?" + "\nThere's really no going back!")) {window.location = "delete_user.php?user_id=" + user_id;}}</script>
```

Here is the PHP:
The show_users script sends this into the viewer:

```
$delete_user_script = <<<EOD
function delete_user(user_id) 
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?" 
                + "\nThere's really no going back!")) 
    {
        window.location = "delete_user.php?user_id=" + user_id;
    }
}
EOD;
```

The PHP in the HTML was NOT changed from when it was working:

```
<?php 
while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $user_row = sprintf("<li><a href='show_user.php?user_id=%d'>%s %s</a>(<a href='mailto:%s'>%s</a>)<a href='javascript:delete_user(%d);'><img class='delete_user' src='../images/delete.png' width='15' /></a></li>", 
    $user['user_id'], 
    $user['first_name'], 
    $user['last_name'], 
    $user['email'], 
    $user['email'], 
    $user['user_id']);

    echo $user_row;
}
?>
```

And finally, the viewing script that gives us our page source (Note: $embedded_javascript is $delete_user_script):

```
if (!is_null($embedded_javascript)) 
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . $embedded_javascript . '</script>';
}
```

When I mouse over the image to delete the user, it still shows the correct script link ("Javascript:delete_user(%d)", where %d is the user_id) but it's like the function isn't defined anymore, nothing happens. Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your mixing php and js up. one is server side, the other is client side

Comment: Could post a live link, or a link to a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the rendered code -- with anything sensitive bleeped out, or the rendered code copied from View Source. I personally can't visualize the whole picture this way.

Comment: I suspect you're inserting your script to define your `delete_user` function after the script that calls that function.  But I can't tell without seeing the whole thing. Use phpfiddle to show us what you're doing http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Yes I am looking into that. I will have it up in a second. EDIT: It's taking me a moment to become familiar with it, sorry.

Comment: In regards to deltree, I define the `delete_user` function in the header, so that shouldn't be an issue, I wouldn't think?

Comment: Your js is broken @RodApernum. Check answer below .. see if it helps :)

Comment: Dagon, the reason I am using Javascript is to warn the user on client side of the finality of their deletion. So it should be fine, using PHP to write the correct javascript into the page header.

Comment: woofmeow, thank you, but I just had it wrong on the question, I just checked the PHP itself. I have updated the question to reflect the real PHP.

Comment: Everytime I see usage of regular **mysql_** extension, I kill a kitten.

Comment: Sorry, but I've gotta start learning somewhere. :) I also can't figure out how to get this to work at PHPFiddle. I'll post it up but it won't render (depends on a lot going on with my database, etc.).

Comment: I know you have to, but bad education hurts, I know how hard it was for me to get rid of plain old **mysql_**, here's a basic reference for better mysql ;) http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: Where's the darn jsfiddle already?!

Comment: Not coming, it was solved, thanks. And thanks for the link, Christian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your `if` statement is wrong (even in the `$delete_user_script` variable). Since it is starting on a new line the interpreter will assume a `;` at the end of it and thus your `if` statement breaks.

Your function has this

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?" 
                + "\nThere's really no going back!"))
```

It should be this way

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?" + "\nThere's really no going back!"))
```

Sometimes its just a teeny weeny mistake. Hope that helps :)

**EDIT 1**: this was an error in the origianally posted question in the **javascript and php**  code. Now its been edited to reflect that the `if` is not broken. 
**EDIT 2**: I have been told this helped to solve the problem so I'll keep this question here. Hope it helps others too. 
**PS**: If someone wants this removed let me know.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh one is with a linebreak and the other is not. In javascript semicolon is optional. So its assuming a `;` at the end and breaking the function.

Comment: Thanks, but the code is actually `function delete_user(user_id) {if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?" + "\nThere's really no going back!")) {window.location = "delete_user.php?user_id=" + user_id;}}` in my page, all one sentence. So tat wasn't the trick (unless that is wrong as well!).

Comment: Ok i ill delete the answer then

Comment: @woofmeow Please don't delete the answer

Comment: @woofmeow I get your point, but there's some information I think would be useful in the comment thread, even though it's unrelated i.e. your first comment

Comment: @RodApernum try commenting out the question and put an `alert()` and build up the function. Generally works.

Comment: A line break like it was originally listed with wouldn't actually cause [ASI](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9) between the lines. Only a few restricted productions force ASI. Beyond those, parsers are willing to look forward before inserting.

Comment: @ChristopherW Ok. I would have been nice to mark certain comments as tips but OK, no problem, I see your point too!

Comment: Ok I am confused guys ... what should i do ? delete or let it be ?

Comment: @woofmeow Lol. At 132 rep I don't think you can afford downvotes so I would reluctantly say you should delete it, even though your tip might be helpful to someone in an unrelated way #ToughBreak. I actually find the process of folks trying to help find an answer almost as useful as the answer itself

Comment: @RodApernum your welcome buddy :). Btw I am still confused about your `$delete_user_script` that has a breakline too in it !!

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh its cool bro ... i believe we are all here to learn so I'll take the risk of downvotes. If anybody finds it useful they can be kind enough to upvote too.

Comment: This led to the answer! I had to take the `/n` out of my script, leading to: `(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?" + "There's really no going back!"))`. You got me thinking about why it was showing up that way. Thank you!

Comment: To be fair, I edited your question to make it more readable. it did not occur to me that your code could break due to word wrap.

Comment: @woofmeow It's a good thing you didn't take my reluctant advice! It's somewhat funny how we find answers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of what you have now in your script:

```
$delete_user_script = "".
"function delete_user(user_id)
 {
    if (confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this user?\" + \"\\nThere's really no going back!\"))
    {
        window.location = \"delete_user.php?user_id=\" + user_id;
    }
 }";
```